# how do I print a Rails POST request output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, request

I have this request:

```
post '/api/v1/fruit', params: valid_fruits, headers: lots_of_security
```

how can I see what's going on behind the scenes and see the many fruits contained in the `raw output` that will be sent after executing it?

Answer (score 0):

`[1] pry(#<Api::V1::InquiriesController>)> request`
returns this very verbose and complete answer:

```rb
=> #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x0000aaaae4ba5308
 @env=
  {"rack.version"=>[1, 3],
   "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x0000aaaae4bdffa8>,
   "rack.errors"=>#<StringIO:0x0000aaaae4be0070>,
   "rack.multithread"=>true,
   "rack.multiprocess"=>true,
   "rack.run_once"=>false,
   "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"POST",
   "SERVER_NAME"=>"www.example.com",
   "SERVER_PORT"=>"80",
   "QUERY_STRING"=>"",
   "PATH_INFO"=>"/api/v1/inquiries",
   "rack.url_scheme"=>"http",
   "HTTPS"=>"off",
   "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"",
   "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"141",
   "rack.test"=>true,
   "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1",
   "REQUEST_URI"=>"/api/v1/inquiries",
   "HTTP_HOST"=>"www.example.com",
   "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
   "HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"application/vnd",
   "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"=>"Bc29dEtvWGiYtmaZGTqL484r",
   "HTTP_COOKIE"=>"",
   "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password],
   "action_dispatch.redirect_filter"=>[],
   "action_dispatch.secret_key_base"=>
    "redacted",
   "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>false,
   "action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions"=>true,
   "action_dispatch.logger"=>
    #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x0000aaaae205d4e8
     @default_formatter=
      #<Logger::Formatter:0x0000aaaae205d678 @datetime_format=nil>,

<page break> --- Press enter to continue ( q<enter> to break ) --- <page break>
```